# Outlook send only account

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, office365, smtp

How can I set up a send-only account in Outlook 356 (on Windows)?

I only have SMTP login information. There is simply no IMAP/POP3 server to log in to.
I've tried this: https://nolongerset.com/send-only-email-in-outlook-2019/
But the "automatically test account settings" checkbox is checked and disabled for me (I can't uncheck it) and therefore I can't proceed with setup.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this tutorial which helped me realize I wasn't follow instructions properly. In order for the checkbox to become enabled, you must select POP3 and type anything in the incoming server field - anything at all, doesn't matter what, but the text box must not be empty.
https://www.codetwo.com/kb/how-to-configure-a-send-only-account-in-outlook/
This tutorial also explains how to avoid the error in the send/receive dialog.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

There is workaround that gives you full access to all configuration fields even on newer Outlook versions. You need to click on `File` tab, then `Account Settings` and `Manage Profiles`

[image: Account settings - Manage Profiles]

Then choose `Email accounts...`. Now, click on `New...` (or `Change...` if you want to edit an existent account) and you will see a lot more settings. This way you can set a null server (insert whatever you want), disable the "automatic test", apply a different username/password for incoming and outcoming emails, etc.

Tested in Microsoft Outlook 2019 and Microsoft Outlook 365.

*Credits for the image: https://www.slipstick.com/*

Comment: As you can see, I've already found the answer. Not only that, I've linked two tutorials that explain how to achieve what I needed perfectly. My mistake was that I hadn't noticed that you need to type ANYTHING into the incoming server field - but there must be something there.

Comment: @TwoUnderscorez well, I felt posting an answer could be useful to other people having the same issue you described. That's the way Superuser.com works, it's not unusual to add more answers to old questions. Second, adding links is useful but posting an answer with full description and images is probabily better for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some research，you could follow below steps to configure a send-only account:

1. Open the Send/Receive Groups dialog
   File-> Options-> Advanced-> button Send/Receive
2. In the Send/Receive Groups dialog press the Edit… button.
3. In the left section, select the account for which you want to modify the send/receive settings.
4. In the Account Options section you can disable the option for “Receive mail items”.
5. Press the OK button until you have closed all open dialogs.

[image]

A similar thread for your reference: [I use Outlook 2016 and need to set up a send only account.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/i-use-outlook-2016-and-need-to-set-up-a-send-only/0b1d6bf7-8ba0-462a-aebe-95db20f0c421)

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but it seems like I would have to configure a valid incoming mail server first, then disable it. That's not an option because I don't have an incoming mail server to log in to with the same credentials. There simply is no incoming mail server.

Comment: You could follow the guidance to configure outlook account automatically, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-an-email-account-to-outlook-6e27792a-9267-4aa4-8bb6-c84ef146101b  if you cannot configure it automatically, you should configure account manually and you must need to know outgoing and incoming pop/imap server.

Comment: That's my problem though, the email address I'm trying to add does not have an incoming server, because there is no mailbox. Any mail this account receives is forwarded to another account (computer science specific mail is forwarded to the general university email account). Do you see the problem? Thanks.